# Правильно ли я посылаю запрос на сервлет?

Tags: java, java-ee, веб-служба, jersey, jax-rs

Во время старта томката , я получаю вывод "Hello" в браузере и вывод в консоле "I am called".

Но при попытке вызвать этот метод через ApplTest, я получаю вывод 
**"InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=GET, uri=localhost:8080/Testing/register, status=200, reason=OK}}"**, но никакого "I am called" в консоль не выводится ..

По логике если респонс 200 то не должно быть проблем и "I am called" должен быть выведен в консоль.. В чём может быть проблемма ?

```
public class ApplTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/Testing/register");
    System.out.println(webTarget.request().get().toString());
}
}


@WebServlet("/register")
public class JerseyDemo extends HttpServlet{

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.getWriter().print("Hello");
    System.out.println("I am called");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`I am Called` должно быть выведено на консоль сервера (томката), а не на консоль вашего Java-приложения. А вы, на сколько я понял, ожидаете увидеть это в выводе вашего приложения.

Comment: Так дело в том что при старте, выводится в консоли сервера "I am called", а при попытке вызова через Main исползьую Jax-RS Client, нечего не выводится. Насчёт ожидания о выводе в консоли моёго приложения по вашему - нечего такого не ожидалось.

Comment: Ок, сорри за мое предположение, но хотелось сразу отсечь очевидные вещи. Возможно, что-то с настройками логгирования в томкате (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html). Кстати, если вы открываете тот же адрес в браузере, какой результат? (по идее, должен быть такой же как и при вызове из вашей программы)

Comment: Да. Но тут дело в том что мне надо протестировать написанное через Java code Main(написать клиента), не используя PostMan, или JSP..